# Mikrotic 6.49.4 queues and mangle

Tags: mikrotik, qos

I'm trying to configure upload and download limits per IP on Mikrotik 6.49.4 using simple queues. Probably I'm missing something similar to disabling 'fastttrack' but even with disabled fasttrack I can not limit download speed for given IP - limiting upload to same IP address works well.
Is there something i should know to enable limit download speed ?

[image]
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The download problem is solved - it was routing/ethernet configuration issue. Packets coming to computer wasn't going thru mikrotik gateway router because there was another mikrotik LTE ruter ( connected to mikrotik gateway router ) that had interface address in same subnet as mikrotik gateway router. Outgoing packets we're going thru mikrotik gateway router but incoming packet's we're directly  going  from mikrotik LTE router to computer omitting mikrotik gateway router.